# Update a column value for 500 million rows in Interval Partitioned table

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

we've a table with 10 Billion rows. This table is **Interval Partitioned on date**. In a subpartition we need to update the date for 500 million rows that matches the criteria to a new value. This will definetly affect creation of new partition or something because the table is partitioned on the same date. Could anyone give me pointers to a best approach to follow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to update partitioning key and the source rows are in a single (sub)partition, then the reasonable approach would be to:

1. Create a temporary table for the updated rows. If possible, perform the update on the fly

   ```
   CREATE TABLE updated_rows
   AS
   SELECT add_months(partition_key, 1), other_columns...
     FROM original_table PARITION (xxx)
    WHERE ...;
   ```
2. Drop original (sub)partition

   ```
   ALTER TABLE original_table DROP PARTITION xxx;
   ```
3. Reinsert the updated rows back

   ```
   INSERT /*+append*/ INTO original_table
   SELECT * FROM updated_rows;
   ```

In case you have issues with CTAS or INSERT INTO SELECT for 500M rows, consider partitioning the temporary table and moving the data in batches.

Comment: @Looks a good way of doing it. But could not perfrom insert operation for a million rows.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... If you have enough space i would create a "copy" of the source table with the good updated rows, then check the results and drop the source table after it, in the end rename the "copy" to the source. Yes this have a long executing time, but this could be a painless way, of course parallel hint is needed.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting copying the whole 10 Billion rows? Or are you talking about Partition exchange?

Comment: yes, you are right, you need to "replace" the update-affected partitions

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to add a new column (Flag) 'updated' bit that have by fedault the values NULL (Or 0, i preffer NULL)  to your table, and using the criticias of dates that you need to update you can update data group by group in the same way described by Kombajn, once the group of data is updated you can affect the value 1 to the flag 'updated' to your group of data.

For exemple lets start by making groups of datas, let consider that the critecia of groups is the year. so lets start to treate data year by year.

1. Create a temporary table of year 1 :

`CREATE TABLE updated_rows
AS
SELECT columns...
  FROM original_table PARITION (2001)
 WHERE YEAR = 2001
...;`

2.Drop original (sub)partition

`ALTER TABLE original_table DROP PARTITION 2001;`

3.Reinsert the updated rows back

`INSERT /*+append*/ INTO original_table(columns....,updated)
SELECT columns...,1 FROM updated_rows;`

Hope this will helps you to treat data step by step to prevent waiting all data of the table to be updated in once. You may consider a cursor that loop over years.

Comment: How is this any different from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26474008/458741) from 4 days ago?

Comment: that will prevent you from updating your big table part by part (Using the criticias of partition) instead of at once => less space used on log file (you can empty your log file between transactions). I am not proposing a new solution it's the same one proposed by Kombajn it seem the good one but incompleted to me.